# How do I remove the date and category form my portfolio pages

Tags: functions, javascript

[This](http://185.105.4.132/~orangeye/portfolio-item/media-central/) is one of my portfolio page

Whenever I wanted to remove dates and category from blog posts I always used this code

```
function jl_remove_post_dates() {
    add_filter('the_date', '__return_false');
    add_filter('the_time', '__return_false');
    add_filter('the_modified_date', '__return_false');
    add_filter('the_category', '__return_false');
    add_filter('get_the_date', '__return_false');
    add_filter('get_the_time', '__return_false');
    add_filter('get_the_modified_date', '__return_false');
    add_filter('get_the_category', '__return_false');
} 
add_action('loop_start', 'jl_remove_post_dates');
```

Since, in this case they are portfolio, I replaced posts with portfolio. But no luck.

Comment: I removed my comment(s) and have add it into my answer, please accept answer so the 'topic' will be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in my comment above, there was not much information to work with.
Assuming that a quick workaround using `CSS code` to overrule settings is enough,
 here a snippet which will hide the output as asked.
*Be aware that this will hide those `CSS classes` for the whole site.*

Add the snippet below at the end of your `style.css` in the folder `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name`.
*Please make always a copy/backup when starting to add/edit files when using `code snippets`.*

```
.edgtf-portfolio-single-holder .edgtf-portfolio-info-item {display:none;}
```

> Note: I use [Firefox -Developer
>   Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) to find
>   specific `CSS properties`.
>  Ofcourse you can use other browsers
>   also, use the right mouse button and select `Inspect Element`.